# Rotational symmetry of rhombicubooctahedron.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am doing exercises of abstract algebra and I encountered this problem. My response was to count number of squares and this would be the size of orbit. And for a square order of stabilizer would be 4. So order of rotation group should be 72(18 x 4). But it actually turns out to be 24. I would have got this if I had taken triangle instead of squares.

What am I doing wrong? I am using the orbit-stablizer theorem.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombicuboctahedron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that not all the squares are "equal". Namely, you have two types of squares: the squares whose all neighbours are squares ($6$ of them), and the squares whose neighbours are squares and triangles ($12$ of them). I say neighbour for the face with a common edge.

Now if you consider the first type of squares, their stabilizers are of order $4$, so the answer is $6\cdot 4=24$. And if you consider the second type of squares, their stabilizers are of order $2$, so again the answer is $12\times 2=24$.